# Why does 'stack smashing detected' error happen when I close the render window in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, stack, stack-overflow, opengl-3, stack-smash

So I'm rendering a basic single Sphere in OpenGL 3.3 using a VAO, VBO, and EBO. I can see the sphere successfully, but whenever I exit the render window, I get this following error.

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is my Sphere class that holds all the data for rendering a sphere.

```
//In Sphere.h. class Primitive is in a different file
class Primitive
{
public:
    virtual void draw(Shader* shader, const glm::mat4& transform) const = 0;

protected:   

    unsigned int _VAO, _VBO, _EBO;

    std::vector<unsigned int> _indices;

    std::vector<float> _vertices;
};

class Sphere : public Primitive
{
public:
    Sphere();

    void draw(Shader* ourShader, const glm::mat4& transform) const override;

private:
    void setupPrimitiveBufferObjects();
};
```

And here is Sphere.cpp

```
void push_indices(std::vector<unsigned int>& indices, int sectors, int r, int s)
{
    int curRow = r * sectors;
    int nextRow = (r+1) * sectors;
    int nextS = (s+1) % sectors;
    indices.push_back(curRow + s);
    indices.push_back(nextRow + s);
    indices.push_back(nextRow + nextS);

    indices.push_back(curRow + s);
    indices.push_back(nextRow + nextS);
    indices.push_back(curRow + nextS);
}

Sphere::Sphere()
{
    unsigned int rings = 20;
    unsigned int sectors = 48;
    float radius = 1.0f;
    float const R = 1.0f/(float)(rings-1);
    float const S = 1.0f/(float)(sectors-1);
    for(int r=0;r<rings;++r){
        for(int s=0;s<sectors;++s){
            float const y = sin( -M_PI_2 + M_PI * r * R );
            float const x = cos(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );
            float const z = sin(2*M_PI * s * S) * sin( M_PI * r * R );
            //This is the vertex position
            _vertices.push_back(x*radius);
            _vertices.push_back(y*radius);
            _vertices.push_back(z*radius);
            //This is the normal
            _vertices.push_back(x*radius);
            _vertices.push_back(y*radius);
            _vertices.push_back(z*radius);
            if(r < rings-1)
                push_indices(_indices, sectors, r, s);
        }
    }
    setupPrimitiveBufferObjects();
}

void Sphere::draw(Shader* ourShader, const glm::mat4& transform) const
{
    glBindVertexArray(_VAO);
    ourShader->use();
    ourShader->setMat4("model",transform);
    //set shader uniforms here
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Sphere::setupPrimitiveBufferObjects()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &_VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &_EBO);
    glBindVertexArray(_VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * _vertices.size(), &_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int) * _indices.size(), &_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // normal attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}
```

Here's the render loop for the sphere.

```
void Renderer::renderLoop(){
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
        glClearStencil(0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0);
        glm::mat4 projection = 
        glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.zoom()), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 2500.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.getViewMatrix();
        primitiveShader->use();
        primitiveShader->setMat4("view", view);
        primitiveShader->setMat4("projection", projection);
        primitiveShader->setVec3("cameraPosition", camera.position());

        //ourSphere = new Sphere; <- ourSphere is defined like this
        ourSphere->draw(primitiveShader, glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0), glm::vec3(14.0, 5.0, 0.0)));

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

I heard that this error happens when your memory is overflowing, but I don't understand why this error appears AFTER I close the rendering window. I also have Cube class that inherits the Primitive class but because it's much simple than Spheres it doesn't give me this error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I changed push_indices() to a member function of Sphere and changed the parameters like this

```
void Sphere::push_indices(int sectors, int r, int s);
```

This resolved the warning. However I still don't understand why this solved the problem. Any explanation would be helpful.